# How do i evaluate a string from a sympy dictionary

Tags: python, sympy

Hi for this code is there a way to evaluate the answers in the sol dictionary instead of a long string of mathematical equation? When I try to access the answers by dict key `sol[i][x]`. It just giving me key error for x. So, I am unable to evaluate it in this way. Is there other way to solve this problem?

This is the error:
KeyError
KeyError: 'x'

This is my exact code:

```
    @app.route('/simult', methods = ['GET', "POST"])
def simult():
  sign1 = ""
  sign2 = ""
  if os.path.exists("data.json"):
        with open("data.json") as datafile:
            saveddata = json.load(datafile)
  if request.method == "POST":
    saveddata["x1"] = request.form["x1"]
    saveddata["y1"] = request.form["y1"]
    saveddata["x2"] = request.form["x2"]
    saveddata["y2"] = request.form["y2"]
    saveddata["px1"] = request.form["px1"]
    saveddata["py1"] = request.form["py1"]
    saveddata["px2"] = request.form["px2"]
    saveddata["py2"] = request.form["py2"]
    saveddata["sign1"] = request.form["sign1"]
    saveddata["sign2"] = request.form["sign2"]
    saveddata["ans1"] = request.form["ans1"]
    saveddata["ans2"] = request.form["ans2"]
    if saveddata["sign1"] == "":
        sign1 = ""
    if saveddata["sign1"] == "+":
        sign1 = '+'
    if saveddata["sign1"] == "-":
        sign1 = '-'
    if saveddata["sign1"] == "x":
        sign1 = '*'
    if saveddata["sign1"] == "^":
        sign1 = "**"
    if saveddata["sign1"] == "/":
        sign1 = "/"
    if saveddata["sign2"] == "":
        sign2 = ""
    if saveddata["sign2"] == "+":
        sign2 = '+'
    if saveddata["sign2"] == "-":
        sign2 = '-'
    if saveddata["sign2"] == "x":
        sign2 = '*'
    if saveddata["sign2"] == "^":
        sign2 = "**"
    if saveddata["sign2"] == "/":
        sign2 = "/"
    saveddata["sign1"] = sign1
    saveddata["sign2"] = sign2
  with open("data.json", "w") as datafile:
        json.dump(saveddata, datafile)
  return render_template("Simaltaenous.html")

@app.route("/res", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def res():
    if os.path.exists("data.json"):
        with open("data.json") as datafile:
            saveddata = json.load(datafile)
    final_lst = []
    final1 = str(saveddata["x1"]) + "x**" + str(saveddata["px1"]) + " " + str(saveddata["sign1"]) + " " + str(saveddata["y1"]) + "y**" + str(saveddata["py1"]) + " = " + str(saveddata["ans1"])
    final2 = str(saveddata["x2"]) + "x**" + str(saveddata["px2"]) + " " + str(saveddata["sign2"]) + " " + str(saveddata["y2"]) + "y**" + str(saveddata["py2"]) + " = " + str(saveddata["ans2"])
    final_lst.append(final1)
    final_lst.append(final2)
    x, y = symbols('x,y')
    transformations=(standard_transformations + (implicit_multiplication_application,))
    eqs_sympy = [Eq(parse_expr(e.split('=')[0], transformations=transformations), parse_expr(e.split('=')[1], transformations=transformations)) for e in final_lst]
    sol = solve(eqs_sympy, dict = True)
    final_ans = []
    final_dct = {}
    for i in range(len(sol)):
        ansx = eval(str(sol[i]['x']))
        ansy = eval(str(sol[i]['y']))
        final_dct["x"] = ansx
        final_dct["y"] = ansy
        final_ans.append(final_dct)
        final_dct = {}
    return render_template("res.html", sol = final_ans)
```

Comment: Are you going to show us `sol`, or at least explain what's in it?  Or do we have to run to code to see for ourselves?  Keep  in mind that we are lazy, and don't do work unless it sounds interesting :)

Comment: Why your question using `flask` tag? You haven't mentioned anything about `flask` in your question!

Comment: When asking about an error, show the exact error, not some paraphrase.

Comment: Your edits have made things uglier!  The symbol `x` has never been assigned to a variable, hence the `NameError`.  Typically a sympy script starts with statements like `x, y = symbols('x y')`.  That both creates a symbol and assigns it to a variable.

Comment: eh even after assigning it with symbols it still gives me the key error. Also, update i have put my full code there.

Answer (score 1):

With your original code:

```
In [45]: from sympy.parsing.sympy_parser import parse_expr, standard_transformations, implicit_multiplication_application
    ...: 

In [46]: eqs = ['2w + x + 4y + 3z = 5',
    ...:        'w - 2x + 3z = 3',
    ...:        '3w + 2x - y + z = -1',
    ...:        '4x - 5z = -3']
    ...: transformations=(standard_transformations + (implicit_multiplication_ap
    ...: plication,))
    ...: eqs_sympy = [Eq(parse_expr(e.split('=')[0], transformations=transformat
    ...: ions),
    ...:                 parse_expr(e.split('=')[1], transformations=transformat
    ...: ions))
    ...:              for e in eqs]
    ...: sol = solve(eqs_sympy)

In [47]: sol
Out[47]: 
⎧   94               74     -53 ⎫
⎨w: ──, x: -20/9, y: ──, z: ────⎬
⎩   45               45      45 ⎭


Out[49]: dict_keys([w, x, y, z])
```

I don't get `NameError` when trying to use `sol[w]` because my `isympy` session already defined variables like `w`, but I do key errors.  The `keys` are symbols, created from the `eqs` strings.

I can get the values by iterating on the keys

```
In [52]: for i in sol.keys():
    ...:     print(sol[i])
    ...: 
94/45
-20/9
74/45
-53/45
```

or even use standard `dict` methods:

```
In [53]: sol.values()
Out[53]: dict_values([94/45, -20/9, 74/45, -53/45])

In [54]: list(sol.values())
Out[54]: 
⎡94         74  -53 ⎤
⎢──, -20/9, ──, ────⎥
⎣45         45   45 ⎦

In [55]: sol.items()
Out[55]: dict_items([(w, 94/45), (x, -20/9), (y, 74/45), (z, -53/45)])
```

I could pull these symbols out of the `eqs_sympy`:

```
In [71]: eqs_sympy
Out[71]: 
[2⋅w + x + 4⋅y + 3⋅z = 5, w - 2⋅x + 3⋅z = 3, 3⋅w + 2⋅x - y + z = -1, 4⋅x - 5⋅z = -3]

In [72]: eqs_sympy[0]
Out[72]: 2⋅w + x + 4⋅y + 3⋅z = 5

In [73]: eqs_sympy[0].args[0].free_symbols
Out[73]: {w, x, y, z}

In [74]: tuple(eqs_sympy[0].args[0].free_symbols)
Out[74]: (x, z, w, y)

In [75]: x,z,w,y=tuple(eqs_sympy[0].args[0].free_symbols)

In [76]: sol[x]
Out[76]: -20/9
```